# About |A| shortest path

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Is there anything called **|A| shortest path problem**. Why is that used for? Please provide any reference to it. I want to know this of my curiosity.

Comment: Sounds most similar to `A*` search algorithm. How do you pronounce this? Modular A shortest path problem?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev , I also don't knpw the pronunciation. I have just found it somewhere, googled for it but didn't find any resource. :(

Comment: I am sorry but I will not be able to help you without any further information. I have not heard of such algorithm.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev , for your reference you can visit: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23558/minimum-path-between-two-vertices-passing-through-a-given-set-exactly-once  -  In one of the answers, a user has given the term.

Answer (score 0):

`|A|` is a notation meaning the cardinality of A or the number of elements in `A`. In the answer you refer to, the user meant you are reducing the problem to several other problems of type shortest path problem and the number of these problems is equal to the number of elements in `A`.

Comment: can you suggest any better algorithm with minimized computation for the problem that is given in the reference?

Comment: @K.Nath sorry but this is a completely different question not related to your original question and it is against the quality standards of stackoverflow to answer it here. If you need to post a new, separate question. This is nothing personal simply these are the rules.

Comment: If you want to answer - you can answer it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956923/minimum-path-between-two-vertices-passing-through-a-given-set

Comment: @K.Nath actually proposed solution is not bad.

Comment: yes I agree ... but complexity arises when |A| increases i.e; say A contains more that 60 elements. Computation gradually increases. That's my concern and for getting a better solution, I have posted the question here.